# Update tables based on NULL values in a derived table

Tags: mysql

I want to start out with this as a basis for my question that I may already know the answer to.

```
mysql> select a.i as AI, a.b as AB, b.i as BI, b.b as BB from a left join b using (i) union select a.i as AI, a.b as AB, b.i as BI, b.b as BB from b left join a using (i) where b.i = 5;
+------+----------+------+------+
| AI   | AB       | BI   | BB   |
+------+----------+------+------+
|    1 | Not NULL |    1 | 0    |
|    2 | Not NULL |    2 | 0    |
|    3 | Not NULL |    3 | 0    |
|    4 | Not NULL |    4 | 0    |
|    0 | Not NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL     |    5 | 0    |
+------+----------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

is there anyway the column AB where = 0 based on the fact that BI = NULL within a joined statement (as the row obviously doesn't exist), and then vice verse, update BB where AI = NULL?

My instinct is NO!!! for a couple of reasons which I am looking to debunk or verify.

1. for the same reason you cannot update a real table with a temptable algorithm based view. I do not believe that you can update a table from the output of a derived table (at least not in such a way as I am looking for).
2. probably the most important reason, you cannot update something based on something else that doesn't exist (or by definition may exist but is an unknown value) due to the fact that without the isnull() function you cannot compare null. That being said to use the isnull() function you would need to have a static table with NULL in it, however due to the fact that in this particular instance the NULL values are only in affect when the tables are joined together (due to the obvious reason that matching rows plainly just do not exist). To perform this effectively you would need to make the values real by creating a derived table... which leads us back to point number 1.

If this IS possible and someone knows how to accomplish this please let me know... also if so is it possible to update both of the values with one statement?

I was about half finished with this command when I realized that it may be useless based on knowledge and other research.

`mysql> update a,b set b.b='n',a.b='n' where   /*possibly a derived table here*/ = isnull((select i1 as 'a.i', i2 as 'b.i' from ((select a.i as i1, b.i as i2 from a left join b using (i) where isnull(b.i)=1) union (select a.i as i1, b.i as i2 from b left join a using (i) where isnull(a.i)=1) as derived1 where isnull(i1))   /*maybe an or statement of some kind and another two derived tables here equalling each other*/  ;`

based on my statement it seems that I would need another derived table or 3 to complete the statement in any kind of complete fashion... although I am not confident that it can work based on my tries up till now.

Also its possible I have been at this for long enough that I am no longer thinking straight.

In any case I appreciate the help in advance (even a this is possible, here is the direction you need to go).

Let me know if I need to provide any further information.

P.S. I do not want to put too much emphasis on my unfinished MySQL statement as It may not even be in the direction that I need to be going... and thus confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a partial answer.  Please let me know if anyone can extend this. also I had to reinstall everything due to upgrading to centos 7.

where:

```
    mysql> (select b.i as '1',b.b as '2',a.i as '3',a.b as '4' from a left join b   using (i)) union (select b.i as '1',b.b as '2',a.i as '3',a.b as '4' from b left join a using (i)) order by 1;
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    | 1    | 2            | 3    | 4            |
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    | NULL | NULL         |    1 | 何もない      |
    |    2 | 何もない      |    2 | 何もない      |
    |    3 | 何もない      |    3 | 何もない      |
    |    4 | 何もない      |    4 | 何もない      |
    |    5 | 何もない      |    5 | 何もない      |
    |    6 | 何もない      | NULL | NULL         |
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The command would end up using the same join syntax:

```
    mysql> update a right join b using (i) set b.b = 'ある' where isnull(a.i) or isnull(b.i);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
    Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

In this case MySQL was able to properly locate the row in `a` that was missing a match in `b` and replace the data as specified.

```
    mysql> (select b.i as '1',b.b as '2',a.i as '3',a.b as '4' from a left join b using (i)) union (select b.i as '1',b.b as '2',a.i as '3',a.b as '4' from b left join a using (i)) order by 1;
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    | 1    | 2            | 3    | 4            |
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    | NULL | NULL         |    1 | 何もない      |
    |    2 | 何もない      |    2 | 何もない      |
    |    3 | 何もない      |    3 | 何もない      |
    |    4 | 何もない      |    4 | 何もない      |
    |    5 | 何もない      |    5 | 何もない      |
    |    6 | ある         | NULL | NULL         |
    +------+--------------+------+--------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best answer for this question or it can get more detailed yet. that is something I would have to do more research on. If this is the best answer please let me know. If not and someone knows the best answer please let me know.